# is there a text editor that allow manual text highlighting?

Tags: text, colors, editor, highlighting

I need a simple text editor to work with some files that i have to manually analyze before putting them into my program. however i would like to be able to manually change the background color and font color of the text i'm working with; to make it easier to see where i have already been.

i'm working with files akin to this one:

```
 #sequence  identifier  exp_freq    occ exp_occ occ_P   occ_E   occ_sig rank    ovl_occ forbocc
ttcttgtt    ttcttgtt    0.0000219976814 28  3.97    4.3e-15 2.4e-10 9.61    1   0   196
tcttgttt    tcttgttt    0.0000210107885 21  3.80    7.8e-10 4.4e-05 4.36    2   0   147
tttttata    tttttata    0.0000121341839 16  2.19    1.7e-09 9.8e-05 4.01    3   0   112
ttcttgct    ttcttgct    0.0000144367046 17  2.61    2.9e-09 1.6e-04 3.79    4   0   119
gttttttt    gttttttt    0.0000167341636 18  3.02    4e-09   2.3e-04 3.64    5   0   126
cttgtttt    cttgtttt    0.0000193716955 19  3.50    6.5e-09 3.7e-04 3.43    6   0   133
ttttttta    ttttttta    0.0000101585213 14  1.84    1e-08   5.8e-04 3.24    7   0   98
```

the aim is to identify sequences that have some feature in common and then group them together, but its really a strain to do it without some sort of marking to sign which sequence belong in which group. i really don't want to use excel, much more comfortable with text editors for this stuff.

what would be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emacs has [highlight by regexp](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/13/highlighting-by-word-line-regexp/).